# abort long running process of a database table : ideas ?

Tags: delphi

I must process a very long database table an think of the most common way to abort this loop. The principal code sequence goes like this

```
 procedure TForm.ProcessmyTable(Sender : TObject);
 begin
 ..... 

 myTable.first;

 repeat
  ReadSingleRecordfromTable ( MyTable, aRecord) ;
  ProcessMyRecord(aRecord) ;
  MyTable.next;
 until MYTable.EOF;

 end;


 unit ....   ;

 procedure  ProcessMyRecord(aRecord : TMyDataRecord) ;
 begin

     //   do not have user interface stuff here
     //   Application.Processmessages  will not work here  !!!


     ....  ( long running code sequence) 

 end;
```

Could do a timer and break the loop based on the timer with var as a flag support ....   but is this really the most clever way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If this code runs in the main thread, then you will need to service the message queue (i.e. call `Application.ProcessMessages`) if you want the user to interact with your program and abort. In which case I think you already know the solution. Call `Application.ProcessMessages`. If the user chooses to abort, set a boolean flag and check that flag regularly in the inner-most loop.

Of course, this is all rather messy. The fundamental problem is that you are performing long-running actions on the GUI thread. That's something you should not do. Move the database processing code onto a different thread. If the user chooses to abort, signal to the thread that it is to abort. For example a call to the `Terminate` method of the thread would be one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to abort? If it takes too long of if the user says 'stop'?

In both cases change your

```
until MYTable.EOF;
```

to

```
until MYTable.EOF or Aborted;
```

then set your Aborted boolean either when the timer triggers or when the user presses a key (note that you then have to use Application.ProcessMessages in the loop for the program to be able to process the keypress). This will not abort *in* your processing routine but after each record. If that is not fast enough you will have to show your record processing routine.

Comment: You'll need Application.ProcessMessages in any case. the timer needs to handle the WM_TIMER message.

Comment: If he wants to break between the iterations - then he does not need a timer, just a `GetTickCount`

Answer (score 0):

If it's such a long process that the user might want to abort surely in a windows app there *should* be some interaction with the GUI, a count of records done or a progress bar (if not on every record then on a periodic basis) any call to update a label or progressbar will provide the opportunity to set an abort flag (so processmessages is not required). Plus if the user can see some progress they may be less likely to abort when bored but 95% complete.

IMHO :)